# Excel: make a field required before saving, but let me save the blank form

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Simply put, I want to make an Excel form that requires the user to fill in 5 cells, if even one isnt filled in then they cannot save the file. The issue is that with my current implementation I cant even save the blank document to be distributed to my coworkers. Is there a way to save once here and THEN have my VBA script work? below I have the code I've made for the form:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim whatCell As String
  whatCell = "B3"
  If Sheets("Report").Range(whatCell).Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "Pls enter value in Submitter"
     Cancel = True 'cancels the save event
     Exit Sub
   End If

  whatCell = "B4"
  If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(whatCell).Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "Pls enter value in Time/Date"
     Cancel = True 'cancels the save event
     Exit Sub
   End If

  whatCell = "B5"
  If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(whatCell).Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "Pls enter value in Customer Info"
     Cancel = True 'cancels the save event
     Exit Sub
   End If

  whatCell = "B6"
  If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(whatCell).Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "Pls enter value in Issue Description"
     Cancel = True 'cancels the save event
     Exit Sub
   End If

  whatCell = "B7"
  If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(whatCell).Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "Pls enter value in Repeatable"
     Cancel = True 'cancels the save event
     Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an empty cell (let's say A1) and put a value in it. Your BeforeSave code checks to see if that cell's populated, and skips the checks if it is. Before exiting it clears the cell.

```
Option Explicit

Dim msg As String

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    msg = ""

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmptyCell Sheets("Report").Range("B3"), "Submitter"
    EmptyCell Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4"), "Time/Date"
    EmptyCell Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5"), "Customer Info"
    EmptyCell Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6"), "Issue Description"
    EmptyCell Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7"), "Repeatable"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following values are required before saving:" & _
                 vbLf & msg, vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub EmptyCell(rng As Range, msgErr As String)
    If rng.Value = "" Then msg = msg & vbLf & msgErr & _
       "   (" & rng.Parent.Name & "," & rng.Address(False, False) & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, So this is to replace my current implementation I'd assume? And follow-up: will it only clear A1 or will all Cells be cleared on re-opening? as I'd need the users input to be read later. Sorry, I'm not really familiar with VB code or Excel macros. EDIT: tested this code, doesnt seem to work. allows user to save w/ a blank document

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you saying you don't even see a messagebox when any of the required cells are empty?

Comment: correct. it just saves the form. I copy-pasted the code here into the VB space (alt-F11, opened code for specified workbook)

Comment: I can't suggest anything.  If you can share the workbook I'll take a look.

Comment: and how would I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I wasn't saving as a macro-enabled form :P you got it!

Answer (score -1):

Find out what your Excel username is and then put this before your 'before save' macro:

```vb
If Application.UserName = "your username" Then Exit Sub
```

In my case, I used

```vb
If Application.UserName = "Florentino, Lais" Then Exit Sub
```