# Excel: Fill out mandatory fields before saving, I need to be able to save the template without filling out the mandatory fields

Tags: excel, vba

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861755/12968783

Looks like someone already answered this but I am not sure why this isn't working for me. 
Every time i save the code, even without filling out the mandatory fields, it saves.

Comment: When you initiate the save action, the macro checks If you have a value in `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")', if there is a value, the code will clear the value and exit. No other actions in the macro will be accomplished. Then your save action will finish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: make a field required before saving, but let me save the blank form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861063/excel-make-a-field-required-before-saving-but-let-me-save-the-blank-form)